# Load image after form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have the following page
[image]

**CODE**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="echipajucator" title="Echipa Jucator">
    <tr>
        <th><div align="left"><span>Echipa</span></div></th>
    </tr>
</table>

<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" id="echipa">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="selectechipa" id="select" onclick="check_list()">
                <option value="AC Milan" id="milan">Milan</option>
                <option value="Juventus" id="juve">Juventus</option>
                <option value="Napoli" id="nap">Napoli</option>
                <option value="Bayern Munchen" id="bmun">B.Munchen</option>
                <option value="Real Madrid" id="realm">Real Madrid</option>
                <option value="Valencia" id="vale">Valencia</option>
                <option value="P.S.G" id="psg">PSG</option>
                <option value="Arsenal" id="ars">Arsenal</option>
                <option value="Man. Untd" id="manutd">Man. United</option>
                <option value="Chelsea" id="chls">Chelsea</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I submit my form I got this table

[image]

```
<form name="atrbjucator">
<table>
    <% 
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String docType = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 " + "Transitional//EN\">\n";
        String title = "Parametrii Jucator";
    %>
    <% out.println(docType +
            "<html>\n" +
            "<head><title>"+title + "</title></head>\n"+
            "<body bgcolor=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" +
            "<h1 align=center>" + title + "</h1>\n" +
            "<table border=1 align=center>\n" +
            "<tr bgcolor=\"#FFAD00\">\n" +
            "<th>Nume Parametru<TH>Valoare Parametru"); 
        %>
    <%-- http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/servlet/useBeanInServlet.html --%>
    <tr><td>Nume</td><td>${jucator.nume}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Prenume</td><td>${jucator.prenume}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Varsta</td><td>${jucator.varsta}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Pozitie</td><td>${jucator.pozitie}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Echipa</td><td>${jucator.selectechipa}</td></tr>
    <%
```

What I want to do is to add a little icon after team's name (AC Milan) acording to the selected team in the submitted table.

PS:
Basic knowledge in java, javascript, jsp, javabeans

I tried to create a javascript in the jsp page with the table

```
function loadImages() {
            if (document.getElementById("select")) {        
                document.getElementById("milan").src = "/HTML-CODE/icons/milan.png";
                document.getElementById("juve").src = "/HTML-CODE/icons/juventus.png";
                document.getElementById("nap").src = "/HTML-CODE/icons/napoli.png";
                document.getElementById("bmun").src = "/HTML-CODE/icons/bayern.png";
                document.getElementById("realm").src = "/HTML-CODE/icons/madrid.png";
                document.getElementById("vale").src = "/HTML-CODE/icons/valencia.png";
                document.getElementById("psg").src = "/HTML-CODE/icons/psg.png";
                document.getElementById("ars").src = "/HTML-CODE/icons/arsenal.png";
                document.getElementById("manutd").src = "/HTML-CODE/icons/machester.png";
                document.getElementById("chls").src = "/HTML-CODE/icons/chelsea.png";       
            }
        }
```

I added the function on body as onload="loadImages()" but I got no image.

Comment: Please show that you've put some effort into solving this. Do you have any code? What difficulties are you faced with?

Comment: Difficulties? As I told, kinda have no idea how to add a icon in that table after team's name according to what team I choose from 1st form.

Comment: @Dave you want to have only one image based on selection by user, don't you? Then why are you loading all the pictures. And if you are, you may initially set opacity of all images to 0, and onchange, you may set opacity of image for selected team to 1.

Comment: @Dave make it clear what you want? the photo after submitting the form according to server side response or without submitting, just after the options are selected?

Comment: Warning: roseindia.net is world's worst Java EE resource. It's so full of bad practices/examples and written by amateurs with zero professional experience who still think that they're in the 90's. That site is heavily misleading to starters as they somehow think that it's "the" resource instead of Oracle's own official resources. I strongly recommend to put that site in your lifetime Internet blacklist and look for more sane learning/example resources. Some are mentioned in our tag wiki pages: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: Thanks for info BalusC, I will!

Comment: @optim, I want the icon to be showed after form is submitted according to server side response right after the team's name.

"Echipa  AC MILAN (icon here)"
I have the folder with the icons too - http://prntscr.com/13p5yv

Comment: @Dave I am not familiar with jsp, but if it loads content dynamically, I think you can change it using javascript. Your form and values will still be there on the same page, right, or would they be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Do this just using javascript, without jsp.

```
<script>
function changeimage(choice){
document.getElementById('icon').src=choice + ".png";
}
</script>

<img src="" id="icon" width='52' height='50'>


<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" id="echipa">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="selectechipa" id="select" onchange="changeimage(this.value);">
                    <option value="AC Milan" id="milan">Milan</option>
                    <option value="Juventus" id="juve">Juventus</option>
                    <option value="Napoli" id="nap">Napoli</option>
                    <option value="Bayern Munchen" id="bmun">B.Munchen</option>
                    <option value="Real Madrid" id="realm">Real Madrid</option>
                    <option value="Valencia" id="vale">Valencia</option>
                    <option value="P.S.G" id="psg">PSG</option>
                    <option value="Arsenal" id="ars">Arsenal</option>
                    <option value="Man. Untd" id="manutd">Man. United</option>
                    <option value="Chelsea" id="chls">Chelsea</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Use this javascript function to change images, make sure to name the images as the option value for them. And extension I am using is .png, if you don't have images in .png you may have to use `if-else` conditions. Like if you have image for Juventus in png, rest all as jpg,

```
if (choice=="Juventus") image="Juventus.png";
else image= choice+".jpg";
```

Your function would now have

```
document.getElementById('icon').src=image;
```

Better would be to change option values as `"Juventus.png", "AC Milan.jpg",` and then strip the extension server side.

Answer (score -1):

I've done it!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function loadImage() {
                if (document.getElementById("jucatorechipa").innerHTML == "AC Milan") {
                    icn.src="HTML-CODE/icons/AC Milan.png";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("jucatorechipa").innerHTML == "Arsenal") {
                    icn.src="HTML-CODE/icons/Arsenal.png";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("jucatorechipa").innerHTML == "Bayern Munchen") {
                    icn.src="HTML-CODE/icons/Bayern Munchen.png";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("jucatorechipa").innerHTML == "Chelsea") {
                    icn.src="HTML-CODE/icons/Chelsea.png";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("jucatorechipa").innerHTML == "Juventus") {
                    icn.src="HTML-CODE/icons/Juventus.png";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("jucatorechipa").innerHTML == "Man. Untd") {
                    icn.src="HTML-CODE/icons/Man. Untd.png";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("jucatorechipa").innerHTML == "Napoli") {
                    icn.src="HTML-CODE/icons/Napoli.png";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("jucatorechipa").innerHTML == "PSG") {
                    icn.src="HTML-CODE/icons/PSG.png";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("jucatorechipa").innerHTML == "Real Madrid") {
                    icn.src="HTML-CODE/icons/Real Madrid.png";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("jucatorechipa").innerHTML == "Valencia") {
                    icn.src="HTML-CODE/icons/Valencia.png";
                }
        }
    </script>
```

Using this script here:

```
<tr><td>Echipa</td><td><span id="jucatorechipa">${jucator.selectechipa}</span> <img align="top" id="icn"/></td></tr>
```